How to combine two formulas in one cell?
There are 4 columns of F7:F, G7:G, H7:H and I7:I. In cell I7 I want to store a formula that checks whether cell F7 is empty. If this is not the case, then calculate and output the content in cell I7. The following formula works for column F7:F. I would like to perform a similar calculation for column G7:G with a second formula. Unfortunately, no further IF can be used. Probably IFS or XOR would be the right choice. What does the compound formula look like?
The result of the first formula with the numerical values of the cells Alpha1 and Gamma1 is to be output in cell Delta1.
The result of the second formula with the numerical values of the cells Beta3 and Gamma3 should also be output in cell Delta3.
 Formula 1:

(F7 - H7) *10000 = I7
(0,84200 - 0,83925) * 10000 =  27,50

(F8 - H8) *10000 = I8
(0,8400 - 0,8300) * 10000 = 100,00 

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(I7:I)=6;"PIPS";IF(ISBLANK(F7:F);"";ROUND(($F7:F-$H7:H)*10000;2))))

The Result will be shown in Cell I7.

Formula 2:
(H9 - G9) *10000 = I9
0,84000 - 0,83000 = 100,00

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(I7:I)=6;"PIPS";IF(ISBLANK(G7:G);"";ROUND(($H7:H-$G7:G)*10000;2))))

The result should be shown in I9.




F
G
H
I




0,84200

0,83925
27,50


0,84000

0,83000
100,00



0,83000
0,84000





It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. The above formulae are both meant for column I? If that's the case, what's the expected output? You have two different calculations based on two different conditions. Prioritise one over the other, or what?

What happens if columns F and G both contain values? If both are empty? By the way, why switch to Greek letters when your formulae and Google Sheets use the Latin alphabet? It's somewhat confusing.

Both cells are empty at the beginning. Either cell F or G is filled, never both cells at the same time.

I think what @user27425627 means to say is that you should give more details about the issue, especially the definitions of Alpha1, Gamma1, Beta3, etc, since it is not clearly defined in your post. Also, what does your expected output look like?

You should edit your post and change Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta to F, G, H, I respectively (based on the post's edit history) to clear this confusion.

I changed the header to F,G,H,I. Sorry for that mistake.

This formula should to the job, according to my grasp of the problem. If I misunderstood, please comment.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(F7:F),IF(ISBLANK(G7:G),"",ROUND(($H7:H-$G7:G)*10000,2)),ROUND(($F7:F-$H7:H)*10000,2)))


